# Merge causes duplicate column names

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a script that is supposed to download prices over time. It returns a dataframe of Date, Product, Price.

I want to combine them and have this loop:

```
for(product in products2){
  series=downloadPrices(product)
  series$date= as.Date(series$date)
  print(product)
  if(new==FALSE){
    combined <-merge(combined,series,by="date")  
    print("merging")
  }else{ 
    new=FALSE
    combined=series
    print("first one")
  }  
}
```

This results in:

```
column names 'underlying.x', 'price.x', 'underlying.y', 'price.y' are duplicated in the result
```

How can I force r to create underlying.z, price.z... and so on?

removing the by="date" results in an empty dataframe.

It works okay if there are only 3 elementsa in product. If it's four, the issue happens.

EDIT:

Dataset downloaded via the downladPrices:

```
date    underlying  price
2012-01-03 00:00:00 Lollipop    -1.66598985
2012-01-04 00:00:00 Lollipop    -2.77954315
2012-01-05 00:00:00 Lollipop    -3.82370558
2012-01-06 00:00:00 Lollipop    -4.90197970
```

Comment: An example dataset would have been better. `underlying.x` and `underlying.y` seems same as `underlying`.x` and `underlying.z`. to me

Comment: added, please have a look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the product name as name for the column:

```
  for(product in products2){
    series=downloadPrices(product)
    series$date= as.Date(series$date)
    series = series[,c(1,3)]
    names(series) = c("date",product)
    print(product)
    if(new==FALSE){
      combined <-merge(combined,series,by="date")  
      print("merging")
    }else{ 
      new=FALSE
      combined=series
      print("first one")
    }  
  }
```

**updated after details on the target format was added, old below text only included for reference**

I would recommend using rbind instead of merge (see below for the code). This results in a different data format (each observation of a price point then has one row), but it works and is - in my oppinion - closer to how you would normally structure this kind of data.

```
 for(product in products2){
     series=downloadPrices(product)
     series$date= as.Date(series$date)
     print(product)
     if(new==FALSE){
         combined <-rbind(combined,series)  
         print("merging")
     }else{ 
         new=FALSE
         combined=series
         print("first one")
     }  
  }
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however it is not suitable for my purpose. Also personally I think it makes more sense to have a separate column for each product.

Comment: Now I understand the format you are aiming for. However, even your code does not get you there, as you have two columns per product, not one (underlying_i and price_i). I'm updating my answer to show how to get to your target format easily.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the issue by adding the rename line... it ain't pretty but it does the job.

I needed to keep the current format of:

```
date product product2 product3
a    b       c        d
a    b       c        d
a    b       c        d
```

So rbind didn't fit the bill.

For anyone who is interested, I used the plyr library.

```
 i=1
 for(product in products){
   series=downloadSpotByName(product, spotDateStart, dateEnd)
   series=rename(series, c("underlying"=paste("underlying",i,sep=""),"price"=paste("price",i,sep="")))
   series$date= as.Date(series$date)
   print(product)
   if(new==FALSE){
     combined <-merge(combined,series,by="date")  
     print("merging")
   }else{ 
     new=FALSE
     combined=series
     print("first one")
   }
  i=i+1
 }
```